# How to clone a object in winrt javascript?

Tags: javascript, windows-runtime, clone

I am working on a winrt javascript project and in a situation where I want to create a object clone. How can I clone a object in javascript?

Comment: That depends on the object type, please add some code to your post.

Comment: Maybe take a look at jQuery.extend - https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L240

Comment: Se these:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object